# How to call a function from a html button - Django

Tags: html, django

What I'm trying to do is execute a function when the user clicks the "add to cart" button, the product displayed on the screen will be added to the cart model. So far i've figured out how to add objects to the cart from the shell. What i don't know is how to call a python function with html and how to pass the object to it. Thank you in advance.

my template.html:

```html
{% extends 'templates/header.html' %}

<title>{% block head_title %}{{ object.name }} - {{ block.super }}{% endblock head_title %}</title>

{% block head %}
 {{ block.super }}
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/products_detail.style.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
 <div id='Product-Page'>
  <p>{{ object.name }}</p>
  <hr>
  <div id='Product-Image'>
   <img src='{{ object.image.url }}' alt='{{ object.image.name }}'/>
  </div>
  <div id='Product-Details'>
   <p id='Product-Name'>{{ object.name }}</p>
   <p id='Product-Description'><small>{{ object.description }}</small></p>
  </div>
  <div id='Product-Buy'>
   <p id='Product-Price'>{{ object.price }} лв.</p>
   <p id='Product-Quantity'>{{ object.quantity }} </p>

   <form class='Product-Form' method='post' action='#'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class='Product-Button' type='submit' value='Buy Now'>
   </form>

   <form class='Product-Form' method='get' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class='Product-Button' type='submit' value='Add to cart'>
   </form>
  </div>
  <hr>
 </div>
{% endblock content%}
```

my view:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'products/products_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hidden inputs to each form (both of which should be POST methods, not GET) then add a post method to your view. Something like:

```
        <form class='Product-Form' method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="buy-now" hidden>
            <input name="pk" value="{{ object.pk }}" hidden>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Buy Now</button>
        </form>

        <form class='Product-Form' method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="add-to-cart" hidden>
            <input name="pk" value="{{ object.pk }}" hidden>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
```

Then in your view:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'products/products_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        name = request.POST.get("pk")
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)

        if "buy-now" in request.POST:
            #Do something to buy.
            print('buy now ' + product.name)
        elif "add-to-cart" in request.POST:
            #Add to cart.
            print('add to cart ' + product.name)

        return redirect('home')
```

Or you can do it via AJAX if you don't want to reload the page.